# PyGame is not drawing circles properly

Tags: python, pygame

```
def collide(p1, p2):
    dx = p1.x - p2.x
    dy = p1.y - p2.y
    dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)

    if dist < p1.size + p2.size:
        for i in range (0,1):
            neutrList.append(Neutron(xxx,yyy))
        for k,neutroon in enumerate(neutrList):
            neutroon.verletUpdate(dt)
            neutroon.bounce()
            neutroon.display()       

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill(background_colour)
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill(background_colour)

    for k, at in enumerate(partList):
        neutron.verletUpdate(dt)
        neutron.bounce()
        collide(at, neutron)
        if not len(neutrList):
            neutron.display()
        at.display()

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

This is a part of my program. I wanted to draw green circle moving away from blue circle.Blue circle is static and is fine. But instead of green circle I get something like this
[image]
What should I change to make my code working properly?

Neutron class

```
class Neutron():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vx = 2.5
        self.vy = 0
        self.A = 235
        self.Z = 92
        self.size = 20
        self.colour = (0, 255, 0)
        self.thickness = 0

    def verletUpdate(self,dt):
        self.x = self.x + dt * self.vx
        self.y = self.y + dt * self.vy

    def display(self):
       pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.size, self.thickness)

    def bounce(self):
        if self.x > width - self.size:
            self.x = 2*(width - self.size) - self.x
            self.vx = -self.vx

        elif self.x < self.size:
            self.x = 2*self.size - self.x
            self.vx = -self.vx

        if self.y > height - self.size:
            self.y = 2*(height - self.size) - self.y
            self.vy= -self.vy

        elif self.y < self.size:
            self.y = 2*self.size - self.y
            self.vy = -self.vy
```

Comment: Erase it before drawing the next one.

Comment: @Jongware How Can I do that?

Comment: Could you post the neurton class code?

Comment: @ballsdotballs added to post

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason you are seeing the smear is because you are drawing a whole bunch of neutrons.  You are creating a new one when running the `collide()` function.  See this line:

```
neutrList.append(Neutron(xxx,yyy))
```

You are appending a new neutron to your list, and when you go to draw them, you are drawing all of them, each with a slightly different position.  You should check this by printing `len(neutrlist)` every frame and see if it is constantly growing.

Also, why is your `collide()` fuction drawing and creating neutrons?  Should it just adjust their position/velocity based on collisions?  It is not a good design choice to have a collision check function draw and create the objects that are colliding.  Neutron drawing and creating should happen elsewhere in your program.